# Retrieving part of a string in excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to extract a part of a string in Excel (Excel for Mac ver.15.33) but I cannot figure out an appropriate formula structure.

Consider the following string in Excel cell A1:

Description:Guanine nucleotide-binding protein alpha-4 subunit:Gopi K. Podila:2006-05-06 Model Notes:editing needed -- 3' only editing needed at the middle portion of G protein alpha domain also:Gopi K. Podila:2006-05-06 Defline:Guanine nucleotide-binding protein alpha-4 subunit:Gopi K. Podila:2006-05-06 Literature:TITLE The genome sequence of Ustilago maydis:Gopi K. Podila:2006-02-10

I would like to extract everything between "Description:" and the first next ":" to appear.
I would also like to extract everything between "Defline:" and the first next ":" to appear.
Note that not every string i would like to perform this on will start with "Description:". The string can also start with "Defline:" or "Model Notes:" or other. The only constant is that whatever I would like to extract is placed in between "A Word:" and ":".

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: try to share more details as what you tried yourself and how this isn't working for you. SA is no free coding service ;)

Answer (score 1):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,":",REPT(" ",999)),2*999-998,999))
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

If *"Description:"* can occur anywhere in **A1**, then use:

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,FIND("Description:",A1)+LEN("Description:"),FIND(":",A1,FIND("Description:",A1)+LEN("Description:"))-(FIND("Description:",A1)+LEN("Description:"))))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I do not see how this formula could work. I tried the following formula before: =LEFT(MID(A1,FIND("Description:",A1)+12,LEN(A1)),FIND(":",MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)+1,LEN(A1)))-1). This successfully retrieves  everything between "Description:" and the next ":", but it will only work if the string starts with "Discription:", which is not always the case and it won't work to retrieve in the middle of the text.

Comment: @Belua Did you try it?  It returns everything between the first `:` and the second `:`.

Comment: I agree that the formula described successfully retrieves the target string and it does so for all strings, but it only retrieves the very first descriptor. As I do not understand how this formula works, how could it be modified to extract the text between "Defline:" and the first following ":" for example?

Comment: @Belua  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: @Gary's Student Your edit #1 works perfectly! Thanks a million!